# SQL statement with square brackets AUTO_INCREMENT error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My new `VPN` accepts only `sql statements` with square brackets hence I edited the traditional `sql query` to:

```
CREATE TABLE admin (
  [id] int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  [name] varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  [email] varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

But it shows this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1  Incorrect syntax near
>   'AUTO_INCREMENT'

Basically the server is windows azure and I am using `Microsoft SQL server` management studio to execute `sql` queries.

Comment: It is MySql or MS SQL??

Comment: please use identity and then no need of any NOT NULL constraints and primarykey

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[admin](
    [id] [int](11) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [email] [varchar](64) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_admin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql server should be created auto increment to use IDENTITY not AUTO_INCREMENT. Like this

```
CREATE TABLE admin (
  [id] int(11) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
  [name] varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  [email] varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

More detail to refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[admin](
[ID] [int]IDENTITY(1,2) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[name] [char](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[email] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [ID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
                        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```